# Trying to remove a property from an input (textbox)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I add this in my Render method (custom webcontrol):

```
 Me.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "chang(event,this);")
```

If affects some textboxes if they have some properties. But there are times that i don't want this property to be set, so no javascript will be executed. I've tried to remove it in code-behind on page_load and i was going to try to remove it on prerender method but it happens before my controls Render method.

How can i remove this property?

Comment: Why can't you define a `Boolean` property to specify if this method should be executed on clientside? Then you set it from the page whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ASP Events Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28VS.100%29.aspx). As you can see, the render event is at the bottom of the execution list. Since no events are fired after render, and render is where you are adding this functionality, then render is also where you must remove this functionality.

You could try to move the function that adds it into a higher event (load for example) and then remove it on render. Either that, or when you are applying it, perform any checks to see if the objects requires it or not.